# How can I read all the the mails (seen/unseen) from a "particular folder" using imap in php?

Tags: php, imap

```
$inbox = imap_open("{".HOSTNAME.":993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX", EMAIL_USER, EMAIL_PASSWORD);

$emails = imap_search($inbox,'all');
```

This is what I'm doing. But this is reading all the mails. Suppose the folder name from where I want to read the mail is "temp". How should I read only the mails that are there in this folder?

Comment: See example 2 here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php

Comment: Open that folder instead of `INBOX`.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to select the folder you want to open.
This code will help you to get the list of folders:

```
    $list = imap_getmailboxes($imap_stream, "{imap.HOSTNAME.com:993/imap/ssl}", "*");
    if (is_array($list)) {
            foreach ($list as $key => $val) {
               echo "($key) ";
               echo imap_utf7_decode($val->name) . ",";
     echo "'" . $val->delimiter . "',";
     echo $val->attributes . "<br />\n";
    }
    } else {
      echo "imap_getmailboxes failed: " . imap_last_error() . "\n";
    }
```

And then all you have to do is

```
$inbox = imap_open("{".HOSTNAME.":993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}CHANGEME", EMAIL_USER, EMAIL_PASSWORD);

$emails = imap_search($inbox,'all');
```